# How to add scrol bars to canvas when content overflows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I have an HTML Canvas inplemented and what i'am trying to do is to make the scrollbars (horizontal and vertical) appear in the canvas when there is content overflow.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Canvas have fixed size no overflow i think

Answer (score 0):

First give some height to that div and add overflow: scroll; in that div's css. So when content will cross the height you will see a scroll automatically and you can do the same for horizontal scroll.